# Android Screenshot programming error

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have two `Linearlayouts` (A and B) whose visibility is mutually exclusive to each other in my xml layout. When A is visible then B is GONE (`android:visibility="gone"`) and vice-versa. Both `LinearLayout`s contain a single `ImageView`. I have a button that takes screenshot of the current screen.

Initially A is visible and B is Gone. Press the above button should make B visible and A gone and then take a screenshot and save the resulting image in sdcard. I do not get B visible in the image. A is still visible.

The android code is as follows:

```
 public class AScreenshotActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout zoomed_image,first_set;
    Button screenshot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ascreenshot);

        zoomed_image=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoomed_image);
        first_set=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.first_set);
        screenshot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        screenshot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(first_set.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    first_set.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    zoomed_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if(zoomed_image.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

                    zoomed_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    first_set.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                 Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                 saveBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        });
    }

private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

        File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "screenshot.png");
        FileOutputStream fos;

        if(imagePath.exists()){
            imagePath.delete();
        }

        if(!imagePath.exists()) {
            try {
                imagePath.createNewFile();
                Toast.makeText(this, "CAPTURING SCREENSHOT !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e("FILE INPUT FOR SCREENSHOT NOT CREATED", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        } 
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, fos);

               fos.flush();
               fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("FILE NOT FOUND - SCREENSHOT", e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("FILE INPUT FOR SCREENSHOT NOT FOUND", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
    }

    private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
         //View rootView = context.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();

        View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
          rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
           return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }
}

The xml layout is as follows:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 >  

    <LinearLayout  
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:id="@+id/zoomed_image"
    >   


            <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imgzoom_large"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:src="@drawable/pack01_11" 
             />

        </LinearLayout>    


         <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:visibility="gone"
                 android:id="@+id/first_set"
                  >

              <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/pack01_12"
                    />



                </LinearLayout>     

              <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button screenshot"
             ></Button>   
            </LinearLayout> 

         What is the mistake?? Please help. Thanks A LOT
```

What is my mistake?? Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited >>>>> Tested this Working fine Make sure your views fit into the screen

```
 if(first_set.getVisibility()!= View.VISIBLE){
                    zoomed_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    first_set.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else if(zoomed_image.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE){
                    first_set.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    zoomed_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
```

Comment: No. The addition of the above code results in a screenshot where both the linearlayouts are invisible. Only the button is seen.

Comment: GONE Means Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added. Initially which view is visible and which one is invisible.

Comment: first_set is GONE and zoomed_image is visible. Please see the xml layout code.

Comment: I feel that this line View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();  is creating a problem.

Comment: @GaneshHegde check the edited code its working fine. i have used 2 image so i changed the layout height and width of Linear layout as wrap_content.   Its changing properly.

Comment: I have a non-activity java class and the above code does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes if you store the View instance or activity you can get it from Non Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this one
if(first_set.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                first_set.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                zoomed_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {

           // if(zoomed_image.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

                zoomed_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                first_set.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

Comment: No. The addition of the above code results in a screenshot where both the linearlayouts are invisible. Only the button is seen. This answer also is not working.